# CDF of continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

On a circumference of circle $x^2 + (y-1)^2=1$ point B is chosen randomly. Let $C(Z,0)$ be an intersection point of $O_x$ axis and $AB$, where A is $(0,2)$. Find CDF of random variable Z.

So when I draw a picture I see a triangle $AOC$, $O(0,0)$, the angle $\angle AOC$ is a right angle and $\alpha - \angle OAC$ can take values between $(0,\pi)$. $P(\alpha<y)=\frac{y}{\pi}$. I am looking for $|OC|$ since $\tan\alpha = \frac{|OC|}{|OA|}$ and $|OA|=2$, then $Z=2\tan\alpha$.

Then, $$P(Z<x)=P(2\tan\alpha < x)=P(\tan\alpha < \frac{x}{2})= P(\alpha < \arctan\frac{x}{2})=\frac{\arctan\frac{x}{2}}{\pi}.$$

The solution from my textbook is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan\frac{x}{2}}{\pi}$. Unfortunately, I can't see where is my mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in the range of possible values of $\angle OAC$. It can take values in the range $[\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] $ if we treat the the angle to be negative when C is on negative X-axis. Now, 
$Pr(\angle OAC < \alpha) = \frac{\frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha}{\pi}$ and this will give the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The CDF you gave shows that the probability that $Z$ will take a value less than equal to $0$, is $0$, which is not possible. Whereas, it should have taken $1/2$ probability as it is 50% of the whole $O_x$ axis.

Look at it this way, the PDF of $Z$ is:

$$f_Z(x)\propto \frac{d}{dx}tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2} \implies f_Z(x) = k\frac{2}{x^2 +4}$$

Where $k$ is the normalization factor, derived as,

$$1=k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{x^2 +4} dx = k\pi$$

Since $k = \pi$, now we can evaluate,

$$\frac{1}{k}F_Z(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{2}{x^2 +4} dx = \int_{-\infty}^0\frac{2}{x^2 +4} dx + \int_{0}^x\frac{2}{x^2 +4} dx = \frac{\pi}{2} + tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}$$

$$F_Z(x)= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}$$